# Which HTTP status code to use in a REST API if the resource doesn't exist when POSTing a subresource?

Tags: rest

To create a document for a project in an REST API,

```
POST /projects/1234/documents
```

What status is expected to return if the project with id=1234 doesn't exist?

---

*Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388277/which-http-code-to-use-in-a-rest-api-for-a-subresource-if-the-parent-resource), but dealing with POSTs, not GETs.*

Comment: 404............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: for most use cases similar to what you describe, 404.

More completely: the notion of "subresource" doesn't really exist in HTTP.

Yes, URI have a standard hierarchy of segments, and you can use relative resolution of dot segments to compute one URI from another.  Those semantics do not translate into a hierarchy of resources.

`/projects/1234/documents` isn't a description of a path traversal, it's a key into a dictionary.

As far as HTTP is concerned, it is perfectly fine that `/projects/1234/documents` exists even though `/projects` and `/projects/1234` do not.

Put slightly differently, the metadata in your response, which includes the status code, apply to the `/projects/1234/documents` resource, *and not anything else*.

Note that this goes both directions: not only does `/projects/1234/documents` not imply anything about `/projects/1234`, but it is also the case that it doesn't imply anything about `/projects/1234/documents/5678`.

Your best reference for getting your head around this is still going to be [Fielding's thesis](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1).  It may also help to review [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4)